# pandas how to skip empty file reading a list of csv files

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have 60 csv files:

```
fname[i]  i=0:59
while fname[19] (or maybe some other file) is empty
```

How can I read them to a list without error "pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file"?

Comment: Have you tried catching the exception and just ignoring it?

Comment: are reading in a loop? can't you just before reading check if the file is empty or not.

Comment: `os.path.getsize(file) > 0`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ a filesize greater than zero doesn't necessarily mean there's anything to read.... Create a file just with blank lines for instance and it'll pass the check but will still throw the exception

Answer (score 3):

Use try and catch the exception.

```
try:
    # read your files
except pandas.errors.EmptyDataError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You will be having a list of files, before reading the file just try to check if the file is empty or not.

```
for file in file_list:
    if os.stat(file).st_size != 0:
        # df = pd.read_csv(file)
        # do your stuf
```

Or you can also try catch the error and ignore. (as suggested by Jon Clements )

```
for file in file_list:
    try:
        # do your usual stuff
    except pandas.errors.EmptyDataError:
        print "Found empty file : {file}".format(file=file)
```